# How to find the solution of x for the given set of equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find a generalized solution of x given the following set of equations:

```
A1 + x*(D-A1) = A2
A2 + x*(D-A2) = A3
...
A11 + x*(D-A11) = A12
```

The values of A1, A12 and D are known.

This problem can be solved using the goal seek functionality of excel, but I am looking to find a way in which the value of x can be solved in one step (hence a need for a generalized solution) as opposed to solving it iteratively.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$A_1+x(D-A_1)=A_2$$
$$A_2+x(D-A_2)=A_3$$
$$\cdots$$
$$A_{11}+x(D-A_{11})=A_{12}$$

The equation $$A_i+x(D-A_i)=A_{i+1}$$
can be rearranged as
$$(A_i-D)(1-x)=A_{i+1}-D$$
So let $y=1-x$ and $B_i=A_i-D$. We get
$$B_1y=B_2$$
$$B_2y=B_3$$
$$\cdots$$
$$B_{11}y=B_{12}$$

which is readily seen to have the solution
$$y=\left(\frac{B_{12}}{B_1}\right)^\frac1{11}$$

Comment: you're brilliant! thank so much!